# How to obtain more Crystocrene armour pieces?

Tags: destiny-2

I have picked up a number of quests from Variks on Europa and they require me to be wearing four pieces of the Crystocrene armour set.

I currently have two pieces, so need to find some more but they seem to just be random world drops. I have already collected all the Variks campaign pieces but dismantled them as I did not know I needed them for a later quest.

Are there any reliable farms for these armour pieces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

High value targets drop either the Crystocrene armor or the weapons from Europa. You can double dip on the chest by sparrowing outside of the area until you switch zones, then going back and opening the chest before it despawns.

Also, as Wondercricket said, the first daily Heroic public event in the Eclipsed Zone, while having the sabotage upgrade is guaranteed to drop armor.

You can also farm Empire Hunts. The harder they are, higher the chance for the armor to drop. Good luck.

Comment: What is sabotaged upgrade ? Or do you mean the quests finished, ? What do you mean by the first daily heroic ? Like the first one that Spons for each person individually, or the first after 12a, ?

Comment: [Sabotage is the seasonal upgrades from Variks on Europa](https://www.pcinvasion.com/destiny-2-variks-sabotage-quests-herealways-pieces/). Heroic public events are regular public events which are changed to heroic by triggering specific mechanics during the event. The first heroic one completed after daily reset (5pm UTC).